# Show cart items between 2 columns

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I've a website on http://kratewear.com/test/checkout/

On that page i've added also the Cart table (via woocommerce shortcode).

As you can see. The cart table is displayed underneath the billing details and the payment options block.

I would like to display this cart table between the billing information fields, and the 'your order' overview block.

This is how it should be : (made via paint).

https://i.gyazo.com/6312f956c99132cd6a5d1d1ea0f68151.png

Is this possible via css? Or do I have to edit the .php files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to edit both css and .php file to change the layout of checkout page.Here i have edited your checkout page with Google inspector as per your screenshot.if you could provide me the source file snippets then i will try to change it..

[image]

Comment: This is exactly how I want it! Is there a way I can contact you?

Comment: Yes you can contact me via **skype** if you want.My skype email = **sagordev672@hotmail.com** ...or you can email me @ **Sagorh672@gmail.com**

Comment: Just added you on skype :). Thx in advance!